# Should we change the linked duplicate for this question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/69345/1359) on *Star Wars* canon was (appropriately) closed as a duplicate.  However, [the question linked in the close reason](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars) doesn't fully answer the newer question, yet [this other previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1806/1359) does.

Is it worthwhile to reopen the question, and then close it again with a more appropriate duplicate link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, why not.

Comment: *gasp*! A mod used an HTML comment to post a too-short answer! I better flag this for moderator attenti- oh, wait.